# Why does an cardano token have multiple policys

Tags: cardano-db-sync, token, policy

I stumbled upon Society token, in multi_assets table via cardano-db-sync it has 2 entries with same name but the meta data difference is minimal, as well they're fingerprints are different

---

- policy = 25f0fc240e91bd95dcdaebd2ba7713fc5168ac77234a3d79449fc20c
- name = 534f4349455459
- fingerprint = asset1tpsewdtydk223j2tkx2wh09qptuyge638246u4

https://tokens.cardano.org/metadata/25f0fc240e91bd95dcdaebd2ba7713fc5168ac77234a3d79449fc20c534f4349455459

---

- policy = 24ecd375f858e31b20ec8c16a19b2c4efededf66f1f994325c41dcc1
- name = 534f4349455459
- fingerprint = asset12sq05wm7ujttuzz5v7a3rulgw0zfy2j8e4uez6

https://tokens.cardano.org/metadata/24ecd375f858e31b20ec8c16a19b2c4efededf66f1f994325c41dcc1534f4349455459

---

1. **How to acknowledge which of the entry is the correct one ?**
2. **Are we dealing with an copycat actually, that somebody has made the exact meta data entry?**

Answer (score 2):

When looking from https://cardanoassets.com/ we could see, it might be just an copycat
[image]

Comment: Probably they launched it with the wrong supply in the first place and then they launched the second one with 700M.